# Attempted to load class "User" from namespace "AppBundle\Entity"

Tags: symfony

> Attempted to load class "User" from namespace "AppBundle\Entity".
>     Did you forget a "use" statement for e.g. "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User", "Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Tes
>     ts\Fixtures\User" or "FOS\UserBundle\Model\User"?

[Screenshot of IDE & CLI with error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t252I.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that your class is a copy of the user model from FOSUserBundle. Instead you have to create your own class that extends it, just like described in the documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html#step-3-create-your-user-class

It should probably look something like this:

```
<?php
// src/Entity/User.php

namespace App\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
*/
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }
}
```

Comment: In this documentation is: **namespace AppBundle\Entity;**

Comment: Yes, but you are using Symfony 4's new directory structure. I noticed it in the screenshot and that is why I already updated the code snippet. Just replace `AppBundle` with `App` when you see it in the documentation and you should be good.

Comment: I gave a talk on upgrading to Symfony 4 and maybe the slides will help you understand the differences: https://speakerdeck.com/dbrumann/getting-started-with-symfony-4-and-flex?slide=17